# How to change background color for a specific <tr> in AngularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How can I set a different background color for every row?
For exemple:

row1: blue

row2: red

row3: green

> main.js

```
$scope.names = [
        {fName: "John", lName: "David"},
        {fName: "Richard", lName: "Daniel"},
        {fName: "Paul", lName: "Mark"}
        ];
```

> test.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody><tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{name.fName}}</td>
    <td>{{name.lName}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just want to set a specific background color for a specific row. If i have a table with 10 rows i want to be able to set a background color for the row with number 6 for example.

Comment: Will there be a ryhme or reason to the colors? Can you bind the color to the name?

Comment: what determines the row you want to color, its position, or ..?

Comment: Would you consider some jQuery?

Comment: I would like to do this in Angular if is possible.

Comment: you could use ng-class

Comment: but what is the condition that determines the row to change the backgroudn color on?. like is it the third row in table or is the row where fname = "roger". what is the flag

Comment: If is the third row in the table i want the background color to be diffrent.

Comment: see answer from  @Michael just change 1 to three

Comment: With `ng-class` and `$index` you can achieve that easily.

Comment: @TimCodes Almost, the index of the third row is 2 ;)

Comment: @Michael, lol, good catch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like a different color for each row you could use ngStyle

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-style="{'background-color': colors[$index]}">
```

where  your controller states  `$scope.colors = ['blue','red', 'green']`

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="colors[$index]">
```

and add each to your style sheet

```
.blue { background-color: blue }
```

Comment: But what if I want the same color for multiple rows. Let's say the first row and the last one. I have to use $scope.colors = ['blue', ' ', 'blue']? I think there must be a diffrent approach for that.

Comment: @ElviraEmm Then Michael's approach may be better for that, using the $first and $last index methods.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, with angular:

**Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{greenyellow: $index === 1}">
    <td>{{name.fName}}</td>
    <td>{{name.lName}}</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.greenyellow {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

This will style the second row as `$index` is *zero-based*.

**[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/uzt5tzss/)**

Comment: I can see in the fiddle that this demo is working. But in my project is not. I will take a closer look to find where is the problem. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The problem was with the library. I had the version 1.0.4. Changed to 1.3.15 and now is working fine!

Comment: `1.0.4` is old :) Latest stable version as of today is `1.4.7`. The upgrade is indeed welcome!

Comment: In the context of an `ng-repeat`, there are some [special variables](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat): `$index` equal to the index of the current row, but also `$first` or `$last`, equal to true if the current row is the first (resp. the last), or false otherwise.

Comment: Example: `ng-class="{green: $first, blue: $index === 2 || $last}"` will add the `green` class for the first row. The `blue` class will be for the *third* and also the last row. Hope it's clear.

Comment: But if i have an table with 20 rows and I want to set the same background color for the row 1, 5, 7, 14, 19. Is there a way to tell the index where to put the color?

Comment: Then you might consider adding a property on the object binded to the scope, that will give you which class you have to apply (if applicable). Or make a `getColor` function that take the index as an input parameter.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider marking this question as solved, and don't hesitate to open another if you have others.

Answer (score -1):

Below code is used to highlight the selected row .

```
<tr ng-repeat="orderList in orderDetailList track by $index"   ng-style="{'background-color': colors[$index]}">
```

Declare in the controller

```
app.controller("OrderListController",function($scope){
    $scope.colors=[];
    /* call the below function on ng-click
    $scope.addtoship = function(){
        $scope.colors.push(['pink']);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<td>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="addtoship()"> Add to Ship </button>
</td>
```